# DB MySql no funciona en ubuntu 19.10

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, php7

mi problema es que tengo una db en MYsql, la misma funciona en windows perfectamente con php. Migre todo a un sistema Ubuntu 19.10 y no devuelve ningun dato de la DB pero si muestra que la coneccion se realizo con exito. habra algo que tenga que modificar para usarla en Ubuntu?

Comment: y tiene datos? tu pregunta es poco clara en ese sentido...

Comment: aunque sea una respuesta que probablemente no ayude mucho, pero ¿importaste tu copia que hiciste a la DB nueva de xampp, las tablas de la DB tienen algún dato que devolver?

Comment: la verdad no se que datos aportar para que me puedan ayudar mejor. Si a db la importe de wampp, lo que estoy viendo es que la exporte usando maridb y en ubuntu la importe pero usando mysql, puede que este ahi el problema?

Comment: hola si tiene datos que mostrar.  que como digo en windows lo muestra perfectamente, pero migrando todo tal cual esta en ubuntu establece la conexion pero no muestra los datos que deveria mostrar.

Comment: Agrega detalles a t pregunta editando la, no agregues información como respuesta, revisa [ask], saludos.